# Cartesian Product of a list of lists in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, list-comprehension, cartesian-product

I have a list  of lists (in erlang, strings are lists) which looks like this:

> ["abc","def"]

and I would like to get the following combinations in a list returned by a function:

> ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"]

Is it possible with list-comprehension? **I don't know the dimension of the list beforehand**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't know the dimension of the input, then you need to use recursion as @legoscia said:

```
cartesian([H])   -> [[A] || A <- H];
cartesian([H|T]) -> [[A|B] || A <- H, B <- cartesian(T)].
```

A 1-dim input "abc" is turned into ["a", "b", "c"], everything else is recursion.

```
> cartesian:cartesian(["abc", "def", "ghi"]).
 ["adg","adh","adi","aeg","aeh","aei","afg","afh","afi",
 "bdg","bdh","bdi","beg","beh","bei","bfg","bfh","bfi","cdg",
 "cdh","cdi","ceg","ceh","cei","cfg","cfh","cfi"]
```

---

*Edit:* Or easier, yet: Let a 0-dim argument return the set that contains the empty set. I think that's what a mathematician would do, too.

```
cartesian([H|T]) -> [[A|B] || A <- H, B <- cartesian(T)];
cartesian([]) -> [[]].
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have exactly two lists, then you can do it with a list comprehension like this:

```
1> [[X,Y] || X <- "abc", Y <- "def"].
["ad","ae","af","bd","be","bf","cd","ce","cf"]
```

If you have an arbitrary number of lists, you could do it with a list comprehension inside a recursive function.

Comment: Recursive function? You can add as many inputs to the list comprehension as you like, so I guess (explicit) recursion is only needed if you don't know the dimension beforehand.

Comment: I have more than two lists. Can you provide an example for the recursive solution?

Comment: [[X,Y,Z] || X <- "abc", Y <- "def", Z <- "ghi"]

Comment: I don't know the dimension beforehand.